# WebStorm warning when using viewBox property on an inline svg tag

Tags: html, svg, webstorm

I use an SVG tag with viewBox attribute, inlined in an HTML file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html><!-- ... ---><body>
  <!-- ... -->
  <svg viewBox="0 0 17 17">
    <!-- ... -->
  </svg>
  <!-- ... -->
</body></html>
```

Despite the fact it is working (and required here), WebStorm gives me a warinig:

> Attribute viewBox is not allowed here

Am I doing something wrong or is it just a bug in WebStorm?

Comment: please try adding namespace attribute to `svg` tag, like `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` - does it help?

Comment: Yes, it helps, but I'm not sure if it should matter at all if it is HTML and not XHTML.

Comment: please see https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#NewDocumentOverview: "In all cases, for compliance with the Namespaces in XML Recommendation [XML-NS], an SVG namespace declaration must be provided so that all SVG elements are identified as belonging to the SVG namespace."

Comment: Would you like to post it as an answer, so I can accept it, for you to get the points?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try adding namespace attribute to svg tag, like `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 17 17">` - this should solve the problem. According to [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#NewDocumentOverview), "in all cases, for compliance with the Namespaces in XML Recommendation [XML-NS], an SVG namespace declaration must be provided so that all SVG elements are identified as belonging to the SVG namespace."